# Open CMD and execute linux commands after bash command

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I run Windows 10 and I'm trying to execute linux sommands in CMD.
I have installed ubuntu so that I can run bash in CMD

[image]

[image]

Now I want to be able to run commands in this CMD window.
In this case a simple ping command.

First. I can not figure how to reuse the CMD window, I don't want to open a new CMD for every loop.

Second. I want to make sure that the command is done before executing the next in the loop.

```
cmd_shell = subprocess.Popen('start cmd /K bash', shell=True)
sites = ["google.com", "python.org"]
for site in sites:
    cmd_line = "ping -c4 "+site
    # this is where I need help to execute the ping command in the already opend CMD window
```

After I have open and executed bash, I cant find a good way to write in the CMD window.
I did a not so nice solution using pyautogui but I think there's a much better way to do it, but I dont know how.
Help please.
/ BR BaconFlip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized that I did not need a CMD window to do this.

I could just run it in the script like this:

```
sites = ["google.com", "python.org"]
for site in sites:
    cmd_line = '"ping -c4 '+site+'"'
    command = check_output('c:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe -c '+cmd_line)
    print(command)
```